# Get focused element after a keyboard tab only

Tags: jquery, keyboard, accessibility

I'm trying to set a class to a specific element that receives focus after the user hits the keyboard tab for accessibility purposes. Clicking the mouse shouldn't have the same effect. There should just be a class change when the user tabs TO a given element.

My problem is that I can capture the tab event, but it only seems to capture the element that the user is tabbing OFF of, not tabbing TO.

Here's my code to just try and display the class of the element being tabbed to, but this displays the class of the previous element on the page:

```
            $(document).keydown(function(e) {
                if (e.keyCode == 9) {
                    //e.preventDefault();
                    alert($("*:focus").attr('class'));

                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Keydown is where you hit the tab key, Keyup is where you released the tab key so you should be using `keyup()` instead.

Secondly if this is only for a form, then use the inputs explicitly to capture the element that the key was released.

Here is an example code:

```js
$('#frm input').keyup(function(e) {
    if (e.keyCode == 9) {
      //Remove the class from all inputs
      $('#frm input').removeClass('selected');

      //Add the class to the element where tab key was released
      $(this).addClass('selected');
    }
  });
```

```css
.selected {
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="frm">
  <Label>First Name: <input id="fname"></Label><br>
  <Label>Middle Name: <input id="mname"></Label><br>
  <Label>Last Name: <input id="lname"></Label>
</form>
```